# $2(n-2)+1$ does not divide $(n-2)(n-3)/2$ for $n \ge 8$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

> For $n \ge 8$ the number $2(n-2)+1$ never divides $(n-2)(n-3)/2$.

Any ideas how to prove this? I see that $(n-2)(n-3)/2 = 1 + 2 + \ldots + (n-3)$. If I suppose that $2(n-2)+1$ divides $(n-2)(n-3)/2$ then it should also divide their difference 
\begin{align*}
 (n-2)(n-3)/2 - (2(n-2) + 1) & = \sum_{k=1}^{n-3} k - (2n - 3) \\
      & = \sum_{k=1}^{n-4} k + (n-3) - 2n + 3 \\
      & = \sum_{k=1}^{n-4} k - n \\
      & = \frac{(n-3)(n-4)}{2} - n.
\end{align*}
That is all I have, hope you can give me some hints!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $2n-3$ is odd, so it is enough to show it does not divide $4(n-2)
(n-3)$. which is $4n^2-20n+24$.  Do a polynomial division. We get $2n-7+\frac{3}{2n-3}$.

If $2n-3\gt 3$, then $\frac{3}{2n-3}$ is not an integer.

**Another way:** Let $n\gt 3$. Note that $2(n-2)+1$ and $n-2$ are relatively prime. So it is enough to show that $2n-3$ cannot divide $n-3$. This is obvious.

**A Puzzle:** We have given two straightforward arguments that we cannot have divisibility if $n\gt 3$. How did they come up with the weaker $\ge 8$?

Comment: Because part of the exercise was to show that $2(n-2)+1 \le (n-2)(n-3)/2$ beforehand, and this fails for $n = 7$. Btw I like that you gave two solutions :)